# MissingRegistrationforLocation

Tags: azure, web, web-applications

I have some background in developing .NET applications, but I am new to Azure. When trying to publish my first web app, I am getting this error statement:

[image: Error Message]

When logging into the cloud the app is up and running but apparently does not perform the tasks it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your Visual Studio and ensure that you are using the latest version of Azure SDK, and then try again. If the error still occurs, please refer to [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-supported-services).